# count total number sub document in Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want count of sub document in array, without using `$unwind` and `$group` , if possible.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aefead0227bc943df3fedff"),
    "doc" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5af0e877227bc943df401337"),
            "shared_with" : [ 
                {
                    "user_id" : ObjectId("5ad5e57b473e2606e0d443c3"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5af0e877227bc943df401339")
                }, 
                {
                    "user_id" : ObjectId("5adbf029b2da8e380b9321b6"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5af0e877227bc943df401338")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b4d856702d7f52974aab962"),
            "shared_with" : [ 
                {
                    "user_id" : ObjectId("5ac7083ce56c9d304f2fa533"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4d856702d7f52974aab963")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

above is the result i'm getting after lookup, i want to count total number of sub document ('shared_with') inside array ('doc') with documents,

so my desired output is as follow,

```
[{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aefead0227bc943df3fedff"),
   "count":3`enter code here`
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to count the inner subdocuments.

Something like

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "count":{
      "$reduce":{
        "input":"$doc",
        "initialValue":0,
        "in":{"$add":["$$value",{"$size":"$$this.shared_with"}]}
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) aggregation first to loop over the `doc` and find the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the `shared_with` array and then count all the `shared_with`  with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "doc": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$doc",
        "as": "do",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$do._id",
          "count": { "$size": "$$do.shared_with" }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "count": { "$sum": "$doc.count" }
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5aefead0227bc943df3fedff"),
    "count": 3
  }
]
```